# Materialize CSS - Inicializar Pushpin con Javascript puro (sin JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, materialize

Estoy usando MaterializeCSS v1.0.0 sin requerir JQuery con fallas para el componente pushpin.
[Codepen1 Funciona! (JQuery init)](https://codepen.io/varelajp/pen/dwYKEw)
[Codepen2 No funciona (Pure JS init)](https://codepen.io/varelajp/pen/qLOMRb)

La [ayuda Pushpin](https://materializecss.com/pushpin.html) indica esta inicialización con Javascript puro:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems     = document.querySelectorAll('.pushpin');
  var instances = M.Pushpin.init(elems, options);
});
```

También, la [ayuda Pushpin](https://materializecss.com/pushpin.html) indica esta inicialización con JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.pushpin').pushpin();
});
```

Tengo 4 secciones pushpin (ver [cover letter](http://varelajp.byethost15.com/cover_letter/en.html))

```js
//Intento inicilizar los pushpin con Javascript puro así
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var pushpins = document.querySelectorAll('.pushpin');
  var instancesPushpin = M.Pushpin.init(pushpins, {
    top: 0,
    bottom: 1000,
    offset: 0
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Juan Varela - Cover Letter</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />
  <!--Import materialize.css-->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />
  <!--Import styles.css-->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles__.css" media="screen,projection" />
  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="divPersonal" class="block">
    <nav class="pushpin" data-target="divPersonal">
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
          <span class="brand-logo">JUAN VARELA</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="valign-wrapper vertical-align">
      <div class="valign" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="container">
          <br><br><br>
          <h1>JUAN VARELA</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="divSkills" class="block">
    <nav class="pushpin" data-target="divSkills">
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
          <span class="brand-logo">SKILLS</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="valign-wrapper vertical-align">
      <div class="valign" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="container">
          <br><br><br>
          <h1>SKILLS</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="divEducation" class="block">
    <nav class="pushpin" data-target="divEducation">
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
          <span class="brand-logo">WORK</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="valign-wrapper vertical-align">
      <div class="valign" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="container">
          <br><br><br>
          <h1>WORK</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="divInterests" class="block">
    <nav class="pushpin" data-target="divInterests">
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
          <span class="brand-logo">INTERESTS</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="valign-wrapper vertical-align">
      <div class="valign" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="container">
          <br><br><br>
          <h1>INTERESTS</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Sin éxito. Solo se muestra el navbar de la cuarta sección anclado durante el primer 100% de altura. Al hacer scroll hacia abajo y pasar la primera altura de pantalla, desaparece el navbar.

El comportamiento deseado se obtiene usando la inicialización con JQuery del [Demo Pushpin](https://materializecss.com/pushpin-demo.html) (ver línea 160 en código fuente del Demo https://materializecss.com/docs/js/init.js):

```
// Pushpin Demo Init
$('.pushpin').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $target = $('#' + $(this).attr('data-target'));
  $this.pushpin({
    top:    $target.offset().top,
    bottom: $target.offset().top + $target.outerHeight() - $this.height()
  });
});
```

index.js code:

```
/*!
 * Site Proper Javascript (not included in materialize.js)
 * No Copyright
 * No License
 */

M.AutoInit();

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  /* Pushpin Initialization */
  /* This way works! */
  $('.pushpin').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $target = $('#' + $(this).attr('data-target'));
    $this.pushpin({
      top:    $target.offset().top,
      bottom: $target.offset().top + $target.outerHeight() - $this.height()
    });
  });

  /* This way doesn't works! */
  // var pushpins         = document.querySelectorAll('.pushpin');
  // var instancesPushpin = M.Pushpin.init(pushpins, {
  //   top:    0,
  //   bottom: 1000,
  //   offset: 0
  // });
});
```

styles.css code:

```
/*!
 * Site Proper Styles (not included in materialize.css)
 * No Copyright
 * No License
 */
html, body, .block {
  height: 100%;
}

nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li a.active {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

/* Class for when element is above threshold */
.pin-top {
  position: relative;
}

/* Class for when element is below threshold */
.pin-bottom {
  position: relative;
}

/* Class for when element is pinned */
.pinned {
  position: fixed !important;
}
```

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda para inicializar el componente puspin con Javascript puro.